# Stepping up an array in a loop vb

Tags: arrays, vb.net, loops

This code simply completes a shift of characters for every negative variable in the loop. It then displays this text for every loop completed. (The name variable is actually a parameter for one of the subroutines, so does need to remain being called 'variable')

```
Counter = 0
dim counterarray(24)

For variable = -1 to -25
   completeshift()
   displaytext()
   counter = counter + 1
next
```

So in this code, i would like to know how to step up each variable in the array every time the loop is complete. Basically i need the first 
loop displaytext() to go into counterarray(0), the second to go into counterarray(1) etc until all of them have been completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using `variable` for anything so you may as well write,

```
Dim counterarray(24)

For i = 0 to 24
    completeshift()
    counterarray(i) = displaytext()
Next
```

---

probably too elaborate but ...

```
Dim count = 25
Dim counterArray(count - 1) As String

Enumerable.Range(0, count).Zip(Enumerable.Range(-count, count).Reverse(),
    Function(counter, variable) counterArray(counter) = DisplayText())
```

Comment: In the code I have given, i've substituted names for more complicated loops due to a lot of parameters etc. Basically the 'variable' does need to remain sorry, i'll add that to the original.

Answer (score 3):

Not entirely sure what your question is, but if you want that loop to work you need to add `step - 1`

```
For variable = -1 to -25 step -1
   completeshift()
   displaytext()
   counter = counter + 1
next
```

Comment: Sorry you're right, and to clarify i would like each array location to be stepped up every loop. So if you notice how the counter increases by 1, i would like the first displaytext() loop content to go into array location one, the second displaytext content to go into array location two. etc